# Installation Trouble With ATLAS and Nmatrix

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I'm having massive problems installing ATLAS (and therefore NMatrix):

I have run everything as said in the installation "manual" and attempted variations thereof, but still have no working solution to installing ATLAS on Ubuntu. Any help pointing me in the correct direction would be great! There are apparently many issues with this and I cannot seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

The error messages I have received are:
After running: `ATLAS3.10.1/configure -Fa alg -fPIC --prefix=/home/blake/Downloads/outputatlas --incdir=/home/blake/Downloads/outputatlas/include --libdir=/home/blake/Downloads/outputatlas/lib --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/home/blake/Downloads/lapack-3.4.2.tgz`

```
make: `xconfig' is up to date.
    ./xconfig -d s ATLAS3.10.1/ -d b /home/blake/Downloads  -Fa alg -fPIC -Si lapackref 1

    OS configured as Linux (1)

    Assembly configured as GAS_x8664 (2)

    Vector ISA Extension configured as  SSE3 (6,960)

    Architecture configured as  AMD64K10h (33)

    Clock rate configured as 3400Mhz

    Maximum number of threads configured as  4
    Parallel make command configured as '$(MAKE) -j 4'
    Cannot detect CPU throttling.
    rm -f config1.out
    make atlas_run atldir=/home/blake/Downloads exe=xprobe_comp redir=config1.out \
                    args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 33 -Si nof77 0 -V 960  -Fa ic '-fPIC' -Fa sm '-fPIC' -Fa dm '-fPIC' -Fa sk '-fPIC' -Fa dk '-fPIC' -Fa xc '-fPIC' -Fa gc '-fPIC' -Fa if '-fPIC' -b 64 -d b /home/blake/Downloads"
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/blake/Downloads'
    cd /home/blake/Downloads ; ./xprobe_comp -v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 33 -Si nof77 0 -V 960  -Fa ic '-fPIC' -Fa sm '-fPIC' -Fa dm '-fPIC' -Fa sk '-fPIC' -Fa dk '-fPIC' -Fa xc '-fPIC' -Fa gc '-fPIC' -Fa if '-fPIC' -b 64 -d b /home/blake/Downloads > config1.out
    make[2]: gfortran: Command not found
    make[2]: *** [IRunF77Comp] Error 127
    make[2]: gfortran: Command not found
    make[2]: *** [IRunF77Comp] Error 127
    make[2]: g77: Command not found
    make[2]: *** [IRunF77Comp] Error 127
    make[2]: f77: Command not found
    make[2]: *** [IRunF77Comp] Error 127


    Unable to find usable compiler for F77; abortingMake sure compilers are in your path, and specify good compilers to configure
    (see INSTALL.txt or 'configure --help' for details)make[1]: *** [atlas_run] Error 8
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/blake/Downloads'
    make: *** [IRun_comp] Error 2
    ERROR 512 IN SYSCMND: 'make IRun_comp args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 1 -A 33 -Si nof77 0 -V 960  -Fa ic '-fPIC' -Fa sm '-fPIC' -Fa dm '-fPIC' -Fa sk '-fPIC' -Fa dk '-fPIC' -Fa xc '-fPIC' -Fa gc '-fPIC' -Fa if '-fPIC' -b 64"'
    mkdir src bin tune interfaces
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘src’: File exists
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘bin’: File exists
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘tune’: File exists
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘interfaces’: File exists
    make: *** [make_subdirs] Error 1
    make -f Make.top startup
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/blake/Downloads'
    Make.top:1: Make.inc: No such file or directory
    Make.top:325: warning: overriding commands for target `/AtlasTest'
    Make.top:76: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/AtlasTest'
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Make.inc'.  Stop.
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/blake/Downloads'
    make: *** [startup] Error 2
    mv: cannot stat ‘lib/Makefile’: No such file or directory
    ATLAS3.10.1/configure: 450: ATLAS3.10.1/configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
    ATLAS3.10.1/configure: 451: ATLAS3.10.1/configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
    ATLAS3.10.1/configure: 452: ATLAS3.10.1/configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
    ATLAS3.10.1/configure: 453: ATLAS3.10.1/configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
    ATLAS3.10.1/configure: 509: ATLAS3.10.1/configure: cannot create lib/Makefile: Directory nonexistent
    DONE configure
```

Comment: It seems like it's saying you need to install gfortran or some other FORTRAN77 compiler. With that said, you don't need to do a manual ATLAS install any longer for NMatrix if you're an Ubuntu user. And I *think* now you can also just do `apt-get install nmatrix`.

Comment: I'll check again to see if I can get it. Would be really nice if that was recently updated and it is possible to simply do that.

Comment: It's a brand new package. Most recent release, 0.0.9. =)